# Php Mysqli Custom Error Messages

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page using php that interacts with a MySql database using mysqli functions. I would like to suppress all error messages from MySql and Php and log these errors in a database for tracking and history. Obviously I don't want a MySql query to pop up for the user to see, I want a custom message. Something like "Server Error: Please try again".

Is there any each way to implement this into my site?

Comment: Post your existing code please.  If you are doing something like the terrible convention `do_thing() or die(mysql_error());` then the solution is to _not do that_ and instead test for success/failure and return a meaningful message to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help you offuscate the error message for the user.

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF); //Turn off default messages

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM Table ";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($mysqli->error) {
    try {    
        throw new Exception("MySQL error $mysqli->error <br> Query:<br> $query", $msqli->errno);    
    } catch(Exception $e ) {
        // Log your error in db or just output it
        // using $e->getMessage() to log the actual message;
        echo nl2br($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
}

?>
```