# Return MySQL Error Code and Custom Response using Prepared Statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have created a MySQL database and sending `POST` requests to it through my Flutter application and using `Prepare Statement` to prevent `SQL Injection`. I am returning the error messages in a raw form using `mysqli->error`. Here is my code.

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
include("connection.php");

$query=$connection->prepare("insert into parent_child_table(`parent_id`, `child_reg_number`) values(?,?)");
$query->bind_param("is",$parent_id,$reg_number);

$parent_id=$_POST["parent_id"];
$reg_number=$_POST["reg_number"];

if ($query->execute()) {
echo "1";
} else {
  echo("$mysqli -> error");
}?>
```

**What's the problem? / Current Response in case of error**

The error message is in the raw form whenever the database throws an error like this.

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`parent_child_table`, CONSTRAINT `FK_child_reg_number` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`child_reg_number`) REFERENCES `Student` (`reg_number`)) in /storage/ssd1/900/12273900/public_html/add_new_child.php:11
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /storage/ssd1/900/12273900/public_html/add_new_child.php(11): mysqli_stmt->execute()
>   1 {main}thrown in **/storage/ssd1/900/12273900/public_html/add_new_child.php** on line **11**

**What I want to do?**
I want to send a MySQL response code or a formatted error message (which I'll be writing for sure based on the error code). How can I achieve that? Is there any pre-build method? I am a newbie to PHP. I hope someone would suggest me a better solution to my problem. Thanks
**Expected Response**

- Child Already Registered (in case of Primary key violation. I am using composite Primary Key)
- Wrong Reg # or the Reg # doesn't exist (in case of Foreign Key Violation)

Comment: Try to move `$parent_id=$_POST["parent_id"];
$reg_number=$_POST["reg_number"];` above the prepared statements and where you defined `error_codes` array?

Comment: For error messages, you can look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900281/php-mysqli-custom-error-messages

Comment: @AmanjotKaur that array was just a type in this question. I was trying different methods to achieve this. and copied it here. I have updated it. That code is working fine. I just want to return custom error response

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900281/php-mysqli-custom-error-messages

Comment: Also this https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Comment: yeah. that 1st question helped it. You can add this as ans. I'll mark as accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to understand that echoing error messages right away is **not recommended**. As a rule, your application **do not expose its internal workings,** error messages included.

Therefore, `echo $mysqli->error;` (which is the correct syntax for the operation. Neither quotes nor braces are used with `echo` statements.) is not acceptable behavior.

However, checking the actual error message and creating a custom response is a good practice. To achieve that you can `catch` the exception thrown. And write a code to handle your situation. In your case it would be like this

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0); // this will prevent PHP from displaying errors
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT ); // has to be moved in connection.php
include("connection.php");

$sql = "insert into parent_child_table(`parent_id`, `child_reg_number`) values(?,?)";
$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("is",$parent_id,$reg_number);

$parent_id=$_POST["parent_id"];
$reg_number=$_POST["reg_number"];

try {
    $query->execute();
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == /* the code for Foreign Key Violation */ ) {
        echo "Wrong Reg # or the Reg # doesn't exist";
    } elseif ($e->getCode() == /* the code for Primary key Violation */ ) {
        echo "Child Already Registered";
    } else {
        throw $e; // the most important part - ALL OTHER errors won't go unnoticed
    }
}
```

So there are three main changes to your script

- exposing errors turned off (has to be done on a live site)
- try catch added in order to catch the error
- an else statement added to the error handler so you will be informed of all other errors that may occur. You may want to configure PHP to log errors in order to see them.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. 1 thing to clear, where am I supposed to store those errors thrown in last else? I am dealing with PHP for the first time.Thanks

Comment: This question is somewhat irrelevant, as we are talking of all errors that may occur in your code - PHP syntax errors, database connection errors, whatever. By default, php errors are written into a web-server's error log, so you can find them all there. So the exception thrown in the last else can be fond there as well. You may want to check your PHP ini settings `log_errors` and `error_log` for clarity. Also, note that I fixed a typo in the code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the logs. I'll check it out. I have got that point which I was doing echo as echo "$->mysqli->error".

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. I am acutely aware of the fact that answers serve not only for the person who asked but also for the infinite number of people who land on the question from Google. And Stack Overflow often does a disservice promoting bad practices (and MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF featured in the other answer *is* such a practice).

Comment: thanks for making me clear about MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF. I was using that before your answer. I'll change my code accordingly now. :)